# Responsive EDMs (HTML emails) resources/tutorials?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, html-email

I've got a client who's very keen on responsive EDMs (HTML emails). I've got experience with EDMs and with responsive design, but not with combining the two. To be honest, it doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

The EDMs I've coded have been old-fashioned HTML layouts in tables. The idea of adding responsiveness to the mix is a bit counter-intuitive, especially as, although it will work in the Apple default mail clients, some other major clients like GMail will ignore the responsive code anyway.

Has anyone got good resources or tutorials you can recommend on the best ways to combine the two approaches?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same boat as you and I have reservations moving away from tables for HTML email until we can put some older email viewers to rest.  That said, I found some articles from resources I trust on this topic.

How-to: 
http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/responsive/
http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/coding/

Pre-Coded Templates: 
http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-email-templates
http://newcampaignmon.cachefly.net/assets/files/templates/CampaignMonitor-template.zip

Hope that helps.